# Performing multiple actions on the database through sqlalchemy query?

Tags: database, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have some sqlalchemy models `Person`, `Car`, and their join table. I would like to perform multiple actions on the database given a single piece of data, but I am having trouble with building an efficient query. Here are the models:

```
class Person(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    cars = relationship('Car', 
               secondary=persons_cars, 
               lazy='dynamic', 
               backref=db.backref('persons', lazy='dynamic')
    )

class Car(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)


persons_cars = Table('persons_cars', 
     Column('person_id', Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True),
     Column('car_id', Integer, ForeignKey('car.id'), primary_key=True)
)
```

From an API, if I receive some data on a person:

```
{ email: 'hello@blahstuff.com',
  cars: ["audi", "honda", "toyota", "ford"]
}
```

Then the query should be able to:

- Fetch person with email. If not found, create the Person
- From the list of cars, create any Cars that don't exist in the DB. For Cars that exist, fetch them.
- Associate all Cars to Person, if the Person doesn't already own the Cars.
- De-associate any Cars from Person that is not on the list.

Then, if some new piece of information comes in,

```
{ email: 'hello@blahstuff.com',
  cars: ["scion"]
}
```

The database will perform the necessary inserts/updates/removals for this person and cars.

Here is the horribly naive query that I wrote, which is very slow:

```
# fetch or create the person
person = Person.query.filter_by(email=data['email'])
if person.count() == 0:
    person = Person(email=data['email'])

for car_name in data['cars']:
    r = Car.query.filter_by(name=car_name)

    # Car exists in Database, append to Person if not associated
    if r.count() > 0 and person.cars.filter_by(name=car_name).count() == 0:
        person.cars.append(r.first())

    # Car doesn't exist, so create it and append to person
    if r.count() == 0:
        person.cars.append(Car(name=car_name))

# Remove any cars that this person doesn't have anymore
for car in person.cars:
    if not car.name in data['cars']:
        person.car.remove(car)

session.add(person)
session.commit()
```

How can this be improved to be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

If your persons_cars table has a unique index on the combination of persons and cars, then the two obvious improvements would be checking whether .first() exists instead of counting, and using a try-catch clause for Integrity Errors instead of probing for them beforehand.